# Javascript and Cropping Text. Small

Tags: javascript, text, resize, accordion

I have a little problem with my website. As you can see on this page part of the accordion content doesn't resize even though it should be responsive. The headlines do resize.

Could you please have a look at my page and the source code and help me figure out the error?

Comment: How is this a cropping issue, it seems to me that the window is just resized to be too narrow?

Comment: hey thanks for your fast answer, but why can't the text/content adjust to the narrow window like the headline?

Comment: fyi, java and javascript are two different things. I changed your tags to javascript.